# Proposition 5.1 in Introduction to Topological Manifolds by Lee

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

This is Proposition 5.1 in *Introduction to Topological Manifolds by Lee*

[image]

[image]

---

I understand the proof up until the point where he mentions that "because boundedness of $f^{-1}$ implies $F(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$"

But $f^{-1}[\mathbb{S}^{n-1}] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \not\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ so we can't use the Extreme Value Theorem here which is what gives boundedness of a function in the most general case (I think).

This is what the author means I think. I think that the author means that there exists a function $g : \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = d(0, f^{-1}(x)) = |f^{-1}(x)|$ which is continuous and thus $g[\mathbb{S}^{n-1}] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact so $g$ is bounded (by the extreme value theorem).

Hence $\sup(g[\mathbb{S}^{n-1}])$ exists which I'll call $\alpha$. Now pick $x \in \overline{\mathbb{B}^{n}}$, then we have $|x|\alpha \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ $\implies$ $|x| \cdot \left|f^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)\right| \to 0$ as $x\to 0$  $\implies$ $|x| \cdot f^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ for $x \in \overline{\mathbb{B}^{n}}$ $\implies  F(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Is that what the author means? If my analysis above is a bit sloppy then please let me know so I can correct it.

What I'm basically trying to ask is, how can I rigorously show $|x|f^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ for $x \in \overline{\mathbb{B}^{n-1}}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sphere is compact, $f^{-1}$ is continuous, therefore $f^{-1}(\Bbb S^{n-1})$ is compact in $\Bbb R^n$, therefore bounded.

There is no reason to limit yourself to $\Bbb R$-valued functions to apply this argument, what you call the Extreme Value Theorem is just a corollary of the fact that a continuous mapping maps a compact to a compact, and that compacts in $\Bbb R^n$ are exactly the closed bounded subsets.

---

**Edit:**

The fact that $f^{-1}(\Bbb S^{n-1})$ is bounded means literally that there is a positive constant $C$ such that $$0\leq \|f^{-1}(x)\|\leq C\qquad \forall x\in \Bbb S^{n-1}$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is any fixed norm on $\Bbb R^n$.

Therefore $$0\leq \|x\|\cdot \left\lvert\left\lvert f^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)\right|\right|\leq C\|x\|\qquad \forall x\in \Bbb R^{n}\setminus\{0\}$$

$$0\leq \|F(x)\|\leq C\|x\|\qquad$$

Conclude using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that now, but how would I use the fact that $f^{-1}[\mathbb{S}^{n-1}]$ is bounded to show that $F(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0$?

Comment: @Perturbative You have $|x|C$ for some constant $C$ on some punctured disc around the origin. But this tends to $0$ as $x$ does.

Comment: @Perturbative I've added details.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks!

Comment: @Perturbative you're welcome :)